# can android project use submodule's dependency?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have one project named "A" in that I have included one "custom_retrofit" module, now custom_retrofit module contain retrofit library and this module is included in my project A.

Should I need to include retrofit library in project "A".

I have tried to run project A, but project A requires retrofit library when I try to use retrofit, why?
It's already in submodule so, it should fetch from that!

Below is my project A's gradle

```
dependencies {
     api project(path:':custom_retrofit')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4' 
}
```

my custom_retrofit module contain below gradle dependancies

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

    /** Retrofit NetWorking Library **/
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0'
    implementation('com.github.ihsanbal:LoggingInterceptor:3.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u post your gradle code

Comment: HI @RahulAgrawal I have updated

Answer (score 2):

I think in your situation you should use `api project(path:'custom_retrofit')` instead of

`implementation project(path:'custom_retrofit')` you can check [this article](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa) to know the difference between the both

Comment: you had mentioned that retrofit are in sub-module then to use this sub-module in projectA it should be `api project(path:'sub-module')` try this if it dosen't work, could you add screenshot or a diagram of an overview of the project main modules , so we can help